# STS does not recognize Lombok annotations

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring-tool-suite, lombok

I am trying, but without success, to create a test project using STS 3.9.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with Java 8 and Lombok 1.16.20.

"Lombok v1.16.20" Dancing Elephantis installed. " is normally displayed on the About tab.

Procedures I've tried:

- Run lombok.jar and do the installation via GUI.
- Run lombok.jar install via command line.
- Add javaagent in STS.ini
- Add the -Xbootclasspath in the STS.ini
- Run STS -clean via command line.
- Run Maven clean command.
- Scope of lombok in pom.xml

Any others ideas to resolve this?

Comment: I solved the problem. The lombok.jar file from my .m2 repository was corrupted. I deleted the org.projectlombok folder from the local repository .m2 and, after maven re-downloaded the file, everything worked normally.

Comment: You could make that an answer to your own question. :-) Then accept that answer. It may seem weird to do that, but I think its fine, since you did find the answer yourself. And someone else with a similar problem might find it helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

In STS, I right-clicked project > Maven > Update Project (Alt + F5) and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The lombok.jar file from my .m2 repository was corrupted. I deleted the org.projectlombok folder from the local repository .m2 and, after maven re-downloaded the file, everything worked normally.